# Django/Nginx 403 Error on new static files

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx, django-staticfiles

Can't figure out why, but after collecting new static files (`collectstatic`), nginx throws **403 Error**.

New files have different permissions from old static files.

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 django django  115206 Jul  9 15:23 dom.jpg
-rw-r-----  1 django django     884 Jul 23 20:42 error.svg
-rw-rw-r--  1 django django  308934 Mar 11 16:30 header.bmp
-rw-rw-r--  1 django django   20188 Mar 11 16:30 header.jpg
-rw-r-----  1 django django     910 Jul 23 20:42 success.svg
-rw-rw-r--  1 django django    1826 Jul  9 15:23 user.svg
```

As you can see - `error.svg` and `success.svg` have different permissions, that's why `nginx` throws 403.

Do you know how to fix this? I don't want just change permission for existing files, I want universal solution so this never happens again.

**top**

returns this:

```
 9143 django    20   0   59124   6580   4904 S  0.0  1.3   0:07.44 gunicorn                                                                                                                         
 9149 django    20   0  213640  67600   8692 S  0.0 13.5   0:07.91 gunicorn                                                                                                                         
 9150 django    20   0  215224  68680   8520 S  0.0 13.7   0:08.95 gunicorn                                                                                                                         
 9151 django    20   0  215056  68420   8512 S  0.0 13.7   0:09.32 gunicorn
32386 root      20   0  126132   1168    684 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.00 nginx                                                                                                                            
32387 www-data  20   0  127076   4580   3308 S  0.0  0.9   0:03.43 nginx
```

Comment: Do you run your webserver with the `django` user?

Comment: Can you let your server run the command `whoami` and print this to a logfile (or something similar). I have the idea that the server is *not* running as `django`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not sure which server - nginx or gunicorn, I've added results of top command at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Well the top `nginx` is  - if I recall correctly - the one you invoke, that will obtain the port (since ports below `1024` require root access), but then it passes control to a child running with another user, to reduce the risk. What if you add `www-data` to the `django` group?

Comment: For example with `sudo usermod -a -G django www-data`

Comment: I didn't helped, I recollect static files and everything is forbidden

Comment: sudo chown -R username:www-data projectfolder and chmod -R 755 projectfolder

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik can you share nginx config?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried chmod 644 on this files ?

Comment: I think that if I read the question correctly, this was actually what the OP wanted to avoid. Furthermore since the owner is the `django` user, if the server is configured correctly, it should work.